# Moving Exchange .EDB and .STM file to other partition

Tags: exchange, filesystems, file-transfer

Im trying to move my exchange mailbox store to a new partition and i keep running into an error message saying: "**cannot copy insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service.**"

The server is a Dell Poweredge 2850 with Dual Xeon Processors @ 3.00GHz and 4GB of ram. Running Win Server 2K3 R2 SP2 with Exchange 2K3 Standard.

The Store is around 55GB any ideas.

I want to get exchange on its on partition since I need to free up some space on the partition its currently on.

Answer (score 1):

Try using xcopy or robocopy to do your copy instead of just Explorer - that usually resolves this extremely frustrating problem.

Comment: I tried xcopy is robocopy in 2K3 thought that was Vista+ only

Comment: You're right. You can, however, download the Windows 2003 Resource Kit tools for free which includes robocopy. Here's the URL:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displaylang=en.

Answer (score 0):

Exchange has to be moved from Exchange.  Trying to figure it out myself right now.

Answer (score 0):

You want to move the files inside Exchange System Manager.

In ESM, Find your store and right-click, Properties on it.

Go to the Database tab.

Click Browse for your Exchange database and then your Exchange streaming database, navigate to the destination and then click Save. Click Apply and wait a few hours while your 55GB copies over.